# Disable zoom in on Graphana graph panels

Tags: grafana

I am building a dashboard which shows values with definied time slots, like yesterday or last week. The user should not be able to change the time range, so I disabled the time-picker. The problem is, the user can still use the zoom in function on the graph panels. **How can I disable this feature?**

[image: Zoom in description from grafana doc]

Source: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/time-range-controls/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find an answer to this question?